# Getting one element to match the scrolling of another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tall and narrow elements of equal height that are next to each other. When I scroll one of these two elements, I want the other to scroll with it.

How can I do this using jQuery? I've tried the ScrollTo plugin but the documentation is so bad I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with some simple jQuery, as shown in [this example (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/hv2jZ/).

Basically, you just set the `.scrollTop()` of one div to mimick the other on the `scroll()` event handler:

```
$('#leader').scroll(function(e){
    $('#copycat').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: I wonder how to make the scrolling sync if the right-hand element has a horizontal scrollbar and the left-hand element doesn't? The horizontal scrollbar makes the scrolling distance shorter for the right-hand element.

Comment: I ended up calculating the height of the scrollbar and reducing the height of the left-hand element by that much.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through **[this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links)** tutorial and change the code like what you want

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you are looking for, but it needs to be said: what you are doing is bad design, it has been done many times before and has never been part of a nice userinterface. Instead of wasting a lot of energy on creating a solution where you battle the browsers, spend it coming up with a design that works better, and is easier to implement.

In your case: if you wish two lists of objects to scroll together, make them live under a single scrollbar.

For instance if it is two multiple select boxes, just make sure they both have the full height of their contents so their scrollbars become inactive/disappear, and then wrap them in a div with a smaller height and set it to `overflow: scroll`.

In general if you come up against something like this where there is no clear and easy way to do it, stop and think why that is, and maybe you will realize that it is because it is a bad idea.

This will certainly not always be true, but quite often it will.

Comment: "It has never been part of a nice userinterface". Gods, I'd hate to use a `diff` GUI that didn't have it.

Comment: Why? - first of all, several diff tools don't have more than one scrollbar, for obvious reasons - why have two scrollbars if they don't work independently? It seems to me like the seconds scrollbar would take up space for no reason what so ever, unless there was a switch to turn off the simultaneous scrolling feature and make them independent again. I know that for most developers good userinterfaces are hard to grasp, because they are engineers at heart, but exactly this point with having a scrollbar for no reason seems like a no-brainer to me.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because the right-hand element needs to scroll horizontally but the left-hand element needs to stay horizontally fixed, but they need to stick with each other vertically. If you can think of a way to accomplish this without using two separate elements, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: @jason: go here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nsZeC/ - it is quick and dirty only tested in google chrome, but it should work in all modern browsers, and if not, it can be made to work in everything since and including ie6 without problems (just remember to set the doctype so ie doesn't go into quirksmode).